# Installing Netis WF2190 driver on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ kernel 4.2.0-27-generic gives me an error: implicit declaration of function ‘strnicmp’

Tags: wifi, kernel-modules, network-interface

## Linux

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

### uname

```
# uname -a 
Linux qb123 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Installed Linux headers

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic
cd /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/
ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic/ build
```

### Installed driver [Download here](http://www.netis-systems.com/en/Downloads/Details/?id=904)

```
./install.sh
```

## Error

```
...
  CC [M]  /root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
  CC [M]  /root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
  CC [M]  /root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
  CC [M]  /root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
/root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c: In function ‘rtw_android_cmdstr_to_num’:
/root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:239:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strnicmp’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if(0 == strnicmp(cmdstr , android_wifi_cmd_str[cmd_num], strlen(android_wifi_cmd_str[cmd_num])) )
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/root/netis-WF2190-Driver4Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.4_9390.20131023] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

I don't think I have seen this error on previous kernel version `3.*`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Installed [rtl8812AU driver](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU)

```
# git clone https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git
# cd rtl8812AU/
# apt-get install dkms
# DRV_NAME=rtl8812AU
# DRV_VERSION=4.3.14
# mkdir /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
# git archive driver-${DRV_VERSION} | tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
# dkms add -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
# dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
# dkms install -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
```

Reboot and RESOLVED!